# How to use SUMIFS() where ABS() is a condition?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to include ABS() in the condition of a SUMIFS()?  My table looks like this:

```
  A            B       C
1 H.Spread     W/L     Units
2 -0.5         W       1
3 1.5          W       1
4 0            L       -1.1
5 -0.5         L       -1.1
6 0.5          W       1
```

I want to do a formula that sums up the Units when the absolute value of the H.Spread is between 0 and 0.5.

This is what I tried:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,ABS(A:A),">=0",ABS(A:A),"<=0.5")
```

This produces an error.  I know there are many work arounds, but is there any way to include ABS() in my formula and have it produce what I am looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C*(ABS(A2:A)>=0)*(ABS(A2:A)<=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: `ABS(A2:A)>=0` is always true :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C:C; ABS(A:A)<=0.5; A:A>=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your existing formula as long as you array-enter it:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(C2:C,ABS(A2:A),">=0",ABS(A2:A),"<=0.5"))
```

or why not

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C,A2:A,">=-0.5",A2:A,"<=0.5")
```

?